# Unable To Fetch Data From Firebase RealTime Database - Swift / Firebase

Tags: swift, uitableview, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to fetch values from realtime database and display it on a tableview cell. I am not sure as to why I am unable to fetch values but I believe it is from my database reference. My goal is to retrieve the 'Weight' of the item and display it on the label in the cell. If someone could have a look I would appreciate it a lot!

My Realtime Database:

```
Users
 -> User Id
   -> Journal
     -> Date // this is chosen by the user and is saved, Ie; Friday, Apr 30, 2021
       -> Item // this is also chosen by the user and is saved, Ie; Milk
         -> Weight: "20" // this is standard and must be entered by the user.
```

My View Controller:

```
class Test: UIViewController {
        
    @IBOutlet weak var itemsList: UITableView!
       
    var databaseRef: DatabaseReference!
    var items = [Items]()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        databaseRef =  Database.database().reference().child("users/\(Auth.auth().currentUser)/Journal")
        
        databaseRef.observe(DataEventType.value, with: {(snapshot) in
        
            if snapshot.childrenCount>0 {
                self.items.removeAll()
                
                for item in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
                    let itemsObject = item.value as? [String: AnyObject]
                    let Weight = itemsObject?["Weight"]
                   
                    
                    let item = Items(Weight: (Weight as! String?)!)
                    
                    self.items.append(item)
                }
                    self.itemsList.reloadData()
            }
        })
    }

}

extension Test: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    
    
    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return items.count
    }
    
    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = itemsList.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! JournalTableViewCell
        
        let item: Items
        
        item = items[indexPath.row]
        
        cell.lblWeight.text = item.Weight
        
        return cell
        
    }
}
```

Items Swift

```
class Items {
    
    var Weight: String

    init(Weight: String) {
        self.Weight = Weight
    }
}
```

[image: Realtime Database]

Answer (score 1):

From looking at your code, you're attaching a listener to the path `/users/$uid/Journal`, so you get a snapshot with all data under that, so all items for all days.

Your callback will need to handle both those nested levels, but it currently only contains one loop. So the `item` variables in your callback point to a **date** snapshot, and not to an **item** snapshot.

To fix this, nest two loops like this:

```
databaseRef.observe(DataEventType.value, with: {(snapshot) in

    if snapshot.childrenCount>0 {
        self.items.removeAll()
        
        for date in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
            for item in date.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
                let itemsObject = item.value as? [String: AnyObject]
                ...
```

Btw: thanks for naming the `item` variable that way, as it made it much easier to spot the problem quickly.

Comment: Hi Frank, thank you for your detailed reply to my query! I understand the core issue so I thank you for letting me know. I tried your code and the data is still not being read - I am not too sure as to why this is the case but I am using the code as building steps in figuring out the next steps. Thank you so much for your reply.

Comment: You might want to run the code in a debugger and step through the code from `if snapshot.childrenCount>0` in that case. For example, the `item.key` should be `Milk`, which you can then check.